# Approximation of continous functions by $C^1$ functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\colon (0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ be a continuous function and $\lim\limits_{x\to0} f(x)=0$. Prove that exists two functions $g,h \colon (0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ of class $C^1$ such that $g\le f\le h$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0} h(x)=0$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: I've tried approximations of f of class C^{\infty} using mollificator functions but I can not soddisfy g<=f<=h.